# Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

In my react-native project, I am getting the following error message:

> Warning: Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code:
> {"203":{"module":"MyModule","method":"startProcessing"},"276":{"module":"RNFetchBlob","method":"emitExpiredEvent"},"1855":{},"1856":{},"1857":{},"1858":{},"1859":{},"1860":{},"1861":{},"1862":{},"1863":{},"1864":{},"1865":{},"1866":{},"1867":{},"1868":{},"1869":{},"1870":{},"1871":{},"1872":{},"1873":{},"1874":{},"1875":{},"1876":{},"1877":{},"1878":{},"1879":{},"1880":{},"1881":{},"1882":{},"1883":{},"1884":{},"1885":{},"1886":{},"1887":{},"1888":{},"1889":{},"1890":{},"1891":{},"1892":{},"1893":{},"1894":{},"1895":{},"1896":{},"1897":{},"1898":{},"1899":{},"1900":{},"1901":{},"1902":{},"...(truncated keys)...":451}

Can anyone tell me what module all of these callbacks are coming from or how to interpret this message?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue was that an async function was being executed in a loop. The loop was firing off lots of async calls almost simultaneously which resulted in excessive number of pending callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

This was a really hard one for me to track down.

What it came down to: This would only occur when I was running on a low spec device (Galaxy A12). I had a hook that looked like this:

```
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);
  useEffect(() => {
    const t = setInterval(
      () => setState(valueGoesHere),
      200,
    );
    return () => clearInterval(t);
  }, []);
```

To poll a value.

This worked fine on higher spec'd phones but it caused the excessive promise issue. You should comb your code for anything like the above snippet, *especially using setInterval as it will bank up promises and not allow prior ones time to finish before dispatch*.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with an `async function` inside a `useEffect()` while the my device was running debug mode (connected to a debugger). I resolved the issue by disconnecting the debugger.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the issue when I remove [] from useEffect

React.useEffect(() => {
...do somethings
}, []);

and it work when I added it back

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).